# Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object

Tags: php

Our website broke over the weekend and starting returning a fatal error. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the full error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object in app/code/local/Mirasvit/Email/Model/Service/EventGenerateService.php on line 109

Here's the content of that EventGenerateService.php file. Line 109 is a few lines from the bottom `$events = $event->check($eventCode, $timestamp, $observer);`

```
class Mirasvit_Email_Model_Service_EventGenerateService implements Mirasvit_Email_Model_Service_EventGenerateInterface
{
    /**
     * Default strategy - schedule the emails starting from email queue generation date
     */
    const SCHEDULE_STRATEGY_DEFAULT = 0;

    /**
     * Event strategy - schedule the emails starting from event creation date
     */
    const SCHEDULE_STRATEGY_EVENT   = 1;

    /**
     * @var Mirasvit_Email_Model_Event
     */
    private $eventModel;

    /**
     * @var Mirasvit_Email_Helper_Event
     */
    private $eventHelper;

    private $scheduleStrategy;

    private $triggerId = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventHelper = Mage::helper('email/event');
        $this->eventModel = Mage::getModel('email/event');
        $this->scheduleStrategy = self::SCHEDULE_STRATEGY_DEFAULT;
    }

    /**
     * Set email schedule strategy, default or event
     *
     * @param int|null
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setScheduleStrategy($scheduleStrategy)
    {
        $this->scheduleStrategy = $scheduleStrategy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set associated trigger ID
     *
     * @param int
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTriggerId($triggerId)
    {
        $this->triggerId = $triggerId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function generate(array $events, $timestamp = false)
    {
        foreach ($events as $eventCode) {
            $this->registerEvent($eventCode, $timestamp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function registerEvent($eventCode, $timestamp = false, $observer = null)
    {
        $event = $this->eventHelper->getEventModel($eventCode);
        // triggerId exists only in manual generation
        if ($this->triggerId) {
            $triggers = array($this->triggerId);
            /* @var $manualSaveProcessor Mirasvit_Email_Model_Service_EventSaveProcessor_ManualSaveProcessor */
            $manualSaveProcessor = Mage::getModel(
                'email/service_eventSaveProcessor_manualSaveProcessor',
                $this->scheduleStrategy
            );
            $event->setEventSaveProcessor($manualSaveProcessor);
        } else {
            $triggers = $this->eventHelper->getAssociatedTriggers($eventCode);
        }

        $events = $event->check($eventCode, $timestamp, $observer);

        if ($events) {
            $this->eventModel->addTriggerEvents($events, $triggers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $event is not an object.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the object that should be created  by the line `$event = $this->eventHelper->getEventModel($eventCode);` was not created.
You should check getEventModel method of the eventHelper

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Dima. I also found out that the error is only occurring with a specific payment module.